# how reduce image size when upload to server

Tags: android, image-uploading

I have an app that upload and download image from server, this is my code for upload image from gallery to server. I want to reduce image size before uploading image. How to do it?

```
private void uploadmap(final String sfile){

int fbyte,buffersize,cbuffer;

int maxbuffer=1024*1024;

File f=new File(sfile); 

try{

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);

    ///////////////////////////
    URL url=new URL(Main.url+"uploadmap.php");
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setUseCaches(false);

    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("ENCType", "multipart/form-data");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=*****");
    con.setRequestProperty("uploaded-file", sfile);


    DataOutputStream dos =new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes("--*****\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\""+sfile+"\"\r\n\r\n");

    fbyte=fis.available();
    buffersize=Math.min(fbyte, maxbuffer);
    byte[] buffer=new byte[buffersize];

    cbuffer=fis.read(buffer,0,buffersize);

    while(cbuffer>0){
        dos.write(buffer,0,buffersize);
        fbyte=fis.available();
        buffersize=Math.min(fbyte, maxbuffer);
        cbuffer=fis.read(buffer,0,buffersize);

    }

    dos.writeBytes("\r\n--*****--\r\n");

    if(con.getResponseCode()==200){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                maptv.setText(getname(sfile));
                dialog.dismiss();
                sendmap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      

            }
        });

        fis.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    }

}catch(final Exception e){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            pr.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to reduce image size with this code for upload and I dont want to reduce image quality.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Image attaching
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
File file;
multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("someName", file,     ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName());
//Json string attaching
String json;
multipartEntity.addPart("someName", new StringBody(json, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Answer (score 0):

before converting image to file try to compress image bitmap or you can use crop image a little for reducing size..or if you don't want to compress you can send data by changing file to zip here is complete tutorial to do it 
[link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

Answer (score 0):

its my new codes that reduce image size (without lose quality) and send it to server

its a button that select image from gallery:

```
    upmap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.btnanim);
        upmap.startAnimation(animation);
        map.setImageResource(0);
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);




    }
});
```

its a button that uploadimage to server:

```
             sendmap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.btnanim);
                    sendimg.startAnimation(animation);


                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(sendlocation.this);
                    dialog.setTitle("uploading...");
                    dialog.setMessage("please wait");
                    dialog.show();

                    new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            uploadmap(compressImage(mappath));
                        }
                    }).start();



                }
            });
```

its my method for select image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){

    Uri img =data.getData();

    String[] af={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cu=getContentResolver().query(img, af, null, null, null);

    cu.moveToFirst();

    int ci=cu.getColumnIndex(af[0]);



     mappath=cu.getString(ci);



        mappath=cu.getString(ci);

        Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(compressImage(mappath));
        map.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
        upmap.setImageResource(R.drawable.changeimage);


            sendmap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



}
```

its my method for upload image:

```
private void uploadmap(final String sfile){

int fbyte,buffersize,cbuffer;

int maxbuffer=1024*1024;

File f=new File(sfile);






try{

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);

    ///////////////////////////
    URL url=new URL(Main.url+"uploadmap.php");
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setUseCaches(false);

    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("ENCType", "multipart/form-data");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=*****");
    con.setRequestProperty("uploaded-file", sfile);


    DataOutputStream dos =new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes("--*****\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\""+sfile+"\"\r\n\r\n");

    fbyte=fis.available();
    buffersize=Math.min(fbyte, maxbuffer);
    byte[] buffer=new byte[buffersize];


    cbuffer=fis.read(buffer,0,buffersize);

    while(cbuffer>0){
        dos.write(buffer,0,buffersize);
        fbyte=fis.available();
        buffersize=Math.min(fbyte, maxbuffer);
        cbuffer=fis.read(buffer,0,buffersize);

    }

    dos.writeBytes("\r\n--*****--\r\n");



    if(con.getResponseCode()==200){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                maptv.setText(getname(uriSting));
                dialog.dismiss();
                sendmap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                uriSting="";


            }
        });

        fis.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    }



}catch(final Exception e){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            pr.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
              "Upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         });
      }

    }
```

and its my method for reduce image size:

```
public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

    float maxHeight = 816.0f;
    float maxWidth = 612.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }



    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));


    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filename = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);


        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filename;

}

public String getFilename() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    return uriSting;

}

private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    final float totalPixels = width * height;
    final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
    while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a function which compressed image to desired size

```
    public static byte[] getCompressdImage(Bitmap bMap) {



    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bmpPicByteArray = null;
    int lBitmapSize = MAX_IMAGE_COMPRESSED_SIZE;
    // Log.v("ImageUtils", "Size:" + lBitmapSize);
    int lQuality = 105;
    while (lBitmapSize >= MAX_IMAGE_COMPRESSED_SIZE && lQuality > 10) {
        lQuality -= 10;
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, lQuality, baos);
        bmpPicByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
        lBitmapSize = bmpPicByteArray.length;
    }
    // Log.v("ImageUtils", "Size After compress:" + lBitmapSize);
    return baos.toByteArray();

    }
```